# Understanding view - layout relationship

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to kindly ask you to help me understand how does the **view** part "see" the **layout** part in the zend framework. 
In my way of thinking(and I'm thinking like a noob) there should be a root that directs the view (index.phtml) to the layout (designer.phtml) right?
Below is not my code, I'm just trying to make sense of it.

This is the view part of the code, the root of the file is /applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/mts/**applications/modules/designer/views/scripts/index/ index.phtml**

```
        <div style="width:100%; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:5px;">
    <span style="padding-left:10px; font-size:18px;">Designer <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="summonHelp('1')"><img alt="(?)" src="/style/images/help-8.png"/></a></span>
</div>
        <?= $this->leftmenu; ?>
        <div id="picFrame" style="text-align: center"></div>
        <div id="middle_admin_content">

    <fieldset>
        <legend id="bookTitleLegend">Please select a book first</legend>

        <div id="fileBox"><div id="innerBox"></div></div>

        <div id="uploadSuccess" class="statusBox" style="display: none; background-color: #D9F5CB"><span>File Uploaded Successfully</span></div>
        <div id="uploadFailed" class="statusBox" style="display: none; background-color: #EBB9B9"><span>File Upload Failed</span></div>

        <div id="aboutTheBook" style="display: none">
            <form id="aboutTheBookForm" action="" method="post">
                <textarea name="about_the_book" id="about_the_book" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Text" name="saveCoverText"/>
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="bookid" id="bookidField"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

This is the layout part of the code, the root of the file is 
/applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/mts/**applications/layouts/scripts/designer.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>InTech - Design</title>

<?php
echo $this->headTitle() . "\n";
echo $this->headMeta()  . "\n";
?>
<?
echo $this->headStyle() . "\n";
echo $this->headLink() . "\n";
echo $this->headScript(). "\n";
?>
<?
/*
    $jsContainer = $this->Minify_Container();
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/jquery.autocomplete.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/jquery.idTabs.min.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/jquery/jquery.form.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/designer/designer.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js');
    $jsContainer->appendFile('/js/scrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js');

echo $this->Minify($jsContainer, 'js');

    $cssContainer = $this->Minify_Container();
    $cssContainer->appendStylesheet('style/ui.all.css');
    $cssContainer->appendStylesheet('js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css');
    $cssContainer->appendStylesheet('style/site_css/designer_style.css');
    $cssContainer->appendStylesheet('js/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.css');

echo $this->Minify($this->headLink(), 'css');
echo $this->Minify($cssContainer, 'css');
 *
 */

?>

<!-- MINIFIED ABOVE ------------------------->

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/style/site_images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link type="text/css" href="/style/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link type="text/css" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/style/site_css/designer_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/js/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/modules/manager/basic/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/modules/manager/basic/js/plugins/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery.form.js"></script>-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/designer/designer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scrollpane/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/scrollpane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<!-- -->

</head>
<body>

 <div id="dialog" style="display:none; font-size:12px; background-color:#ffffff;">
    <div id="dialog_left" style="float:left; width:150px">
    </div>
    <div id="dialog_right">
    </div>
 </div> 

 <div id="dialogDelete" style="display: none">Delete Item?</div>


    <!-- HEADER SITE AREA :: START -->
    <div id="header">

    <?php 
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$module = $front->getRequest()->getModuleName();

    echo $this->render('header-designer.phtml', array(
        'authenticated' => $this->authenticated
    ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <!-- HEADER SITE AREA :: END -->





    <!-- CONTENT :: START -->
    <div id="contentAdmin">
        <div id="helpDialog" style="display: none"></div>

        <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>




    </div>
    <!-- CONTENT :: END -->





    <!-- FOOTER SITE AREA :: START -->
    <div id="footer">
    <?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml', array(
        'authenticated' => $this->authenticated
    )) ?>
    </div>
    <!-- FOOTER SITE AREA :: START -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific mechanics of how all this implemented involves [bootstrapping application resources](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html) and registering late-running [front-controller plugins](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372).

But the short answer is the "system" knows how to find/render the view-script associated to the requested action and how to find/render your layout script with the view-script content injected.

Remember, at some point, you bootstrapped a `Layout` resource, probably in `configs/application.ini`.

You also bootstrapped a `View` resource - either explicitly or implicitly - which knows how to render your `headTitle()`, `headMeta()`, `headScript()`, etc (all rendered using view-helpers), as well as the layout.

So, there's really no mystery that the "system" is aware of all this stuff.